# How Do You Create A Fluid Simulation In libGDX WITHOUT BOX2D

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've created a simple platformer game in libGDX without box2d. Except I want to create a fluid simulation for water in my game. (It will have a part where you are in water for part of the game). But, all the answers I found online were to do with box2d stuff. But I really want to know how to create it without box2d.
So, is there a way? I have no code yet to show because I really have no clue on where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/make-a-splash-with-dynamic-2d-water-effects--gamedev-236

Comment: yes, you study physics,particles and fluid behavior and implement it by yourself.